# JavaScript: getting text selection does not work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying extract selected text from the browser window **in Chrome**, On the following browsers: IE6-9, FireFox & Safari it's works fine. BUT NOT IN CHROME!!!

Here is my code:

```
$("div-content").bind("mouseup", function () {
       var t = '';
        if (window.getSelection) {          //FireFox, Safari and IE9(*) 
            t = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.getSelection) {
            t = document.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {    //IE6,7,8,9
            t = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }     

 });
```

Anybody knows what is the magic for Chrome?

*Notice that IE9 has 2 possible ways to get the selection: window.getSelection() and document.selection

Comment: it's works in chrome too, just alert var 't'.

Comment: What makes you think it does not work?

Comment: yeah It works. look http://jsfiddle.net/z8CTx/

Comment: By the way, except for IE<9, you won't get a string but a `Selection` object. Can be easily converted to a string, though, just calling `toString()`.

Comment: Solved the Bug: it's the fault of the: Better Pop Up Blocker- Version: 2.1.6.extension. Shame on you pop up blocker!!! The error i was getting was: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'getSelection' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function.